# Change Startup Window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 C#. I have created a WPF application project with a main window and added a login window to my project. I want to change the startup window to be my login window but can't seem to do so.

I went to the properties but all I see there is Myproject.app - should it not display the forms of my project?

Anyway I have tried running the window from code as well like so :

```
Application.Run(new Login());
```

But that does not seem to work. It gives an error saying :

> Error  1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)'

Answer (score 84, accepted):

To change startup window update `App.xaml` by changing `Application.StartupUri`:

```
<Application ... StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

Comment: If your window is contained within a subfolder, you would need to use the relative path. E.g. `"subfolder\MainWindow.xaml"`

Comment: Thank you! I now get the static error when i try to open my main window :  Application.Run(new MainWindow());

Comment: do you still have `Application.Run(...)` in your code or you removed that?

Comment: I removed Application.Run(...)

Comment: So in `App.xaml` you have `<Application ... StartupUri="Login.xaml">`, you removed `Application.Run(...)` and it's still complaining about `MainWindow`?!

Comment: I'm now trying      Close();
                    var m = new MainWindow();
                    m.Show();                   and variations thereof

Comment: I changed the order and now it is working :                          var m = new MainWindow(); m.Show(); Close();

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica, thanks for the added suggestion. Worked beautifully (y)

Comment: `Solution Explorer` -> Program.cs->Program `double click` ->  Application.Run(new Form1()); `Change Form1() to MY_NEW_Window_NAME()`

Answer (score 17):

To change the startup window programmatically go to `App.xaml`
remove the line `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` (This will remove the default startup window configuration), now add the startup event `Startup="Application_Startup"`, in `App.xaml.cs`

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  If(somecase)
   {
     MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow ();
     mainWindow.Show();
   }
  else
   {
     OtherWindow otherWindow= new OtherWindow();
     otherWindow.Show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use Application.Current.Run Instead of Application.Run